# Adding a new index row to an existing dataframe and sorting by it

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a large pandas dataframe, with time series data and a rather large multiindex. Said index contains various information about the time series, such as for example location, datatype and so on.

Now I want to add a new row to the index, with an integer (or float, doesnt really matter), containing a distance to a certain point. Following that, I want to sort the dataframe by this distance.

I am not sure how to add a new index level, and how to assign new values by hand. Also, can pandas even sort columns after an random number in one of its index levels?

**Example**

(code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370402/giving-a-column-multiple-indexes-headers)  )

```
header=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['location1','location2'],['S1','S2','S3']],names=['loc','S'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns = header)
```

Looks like this:

```
loc  location1                      location2                    
S           S1        S2        S3         S1        S2        S3
a     1.530590  0.536364  1.295848   0.422256 -1.853786  1.334981
b     0.275857 -0.848685 -1.212584  -0.464235 -0.855600  0.680985
c    -1.209607  0.265359 -0.695233   0.643896  1.315216 -0.751027
d    -1.591613 -0.178605  0.878567   0.647389 -0.454313 -1.972509
e     1.098193 -0.766810  0.087173   0.714301 -0.886545 -0.826163
```

What I want to to, is in a first step, add some distances to each column, like `location1 S1 add dist 200`, `location1 S2 add dist 760` and so on, resulting in this:

```
loc  location1                      location2                    
S           S1        S2        S3         S1        S2        S3
dist       200       760        10       1000       340        70
a     1.530590  0.536364  1.295848   0.422256 -1.853786  1.334981
b     0.275857 -0.848685 -1.212584  -0.464235 -0.855600  0.680985
c    -1.209607  0.265359 -0.695233   0.643896  1.315216 -0.751027
d    -1.591613 -0.178605  0.878567   0.647389 -0.454313 -1.972509
e     1.098193 -0.766810  0.087173   0.714301 -0.886545 -0.826163
```

And then do something like `df.sortlevel('dist')`, resulting in

```
loc location1 location2 location1 location2 location1 location2
S          S3        S3        S1        S2        S2        S1
dist       10        70       200       340       760      1000
a    1.295848  1.334981  1.530590 -1.853786  0.536364  0.422256
b   -1.212584  0.680985  0.275857 -0.855600 -0.848685 -0.464235
…
```

So that have the whole thing sorted by distance, for things like `plt.matshow(df.corr())`.

Can pandas even sort a df after a random index with an integer? Because I have another dataframe, that already has an integer in its multindex, and here `some_otherdf.sortlevel('HZB')` results in `TypeError: can only sort by level with a hierarchical index`

**Edit:**

As of now, there is two answers, both of which work perfectly fine for my test case.
I think @Pedro M Duarte's answer might be the more correct one, given that it uses the multiindex as intended. However, for my real data, it would require either a lot of reworking, or a lot of typing, for a 7 levels deep multiindex and 50 data series, which is very error prone.
@Nader Hisham ignored my request to stay in my multiindex, but it requires just the quick, easy and easy to check writing of a simple row of numbers (saving me a lot of time), that I can then remove after sorting. 
for other folks with a similar question, it might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [35]:
df.loc['dist' , : ] = [200,760,10,1000,340,70]
df
Out[35]:
loc                location1                 location2
S     S1              S2            S3            S1          S2    S3
a     0.348766  -0.326088   -0.891929   -0.704856   -1.514304   0.611692
b    -0.546026  -0.111232   -1.022104   -1.246002   0.328385    0.576465
c    -0.743512  -0.362791   -0.617021   -0.859157   -0.300368   0.292980
d     0.090178  1.369648    0.171753    -0.411466   0.478654    1.814878
e    -0.380414  -1.568492   -0.432858   1.034861    -0.633563   1.403627
dist 200.000000 760.000000  10.000000   1000.000000 340.000000  70.000000


In [36]:
order = np.argsort(df.loc['dist' , :]).values
order
Out[36]:
array([2, 5, 0, 4, 1, 3], dtype=int64)

In [37]:

df.iloc[: , order]
Out[37]:
loc    location1    location2   location1   location2   location1   location2
S            S3      S3            S1         S2          S2           S1
a     -0.891929    0.611692     0.348766    -1.514304   -0.326088   -0.704856
b     -1.022104    0.576465    -0.546026    0.328385    -0.111232   -1.246002
c     -0.617021    0.292980    -0.743512    -0.300368   -0.362791   -0.859157
d     0.171753     1.814878     0.090178    0.478654    1.369648    -0.411466
e     -0.432858    1.403627     -0.380414   -0.633563   -1.568492   1.034861
dist  10.000000    70.000000    200.000000  340.000000  760.000000  1000.000000
```

if you want to make your `dist` index as the first index you can do the following

Comment: You are just adding a new `dist` row to the data part, of the dataframe, but not to the index. I am not sure if that will not cause me issues with stuff like plotting the series. Will play wwith it a bit.

Comment: Yes, but it is an index like `a`, `b` and so on, instead of being part of the multiindex such as `loc` and `S`. When I do `df.plot()`, It also shows the `dist` part.

Comment: OK, i can just do your way, and after the sorting, delete the line `droppeddf = dfordered.drop('dist')` to get a proper plot. Seems a bit hacky, but maybe faster than Pedro M Duarte's solution. I will play with both for bit and see which works best for me.

Comment: I'll point out that I was shooting for generality rather than speed.  Notice that I used a dictionary to obtain the value of `dist` from the values of `loc` and `S`.   In your application perhaps you have a function that calculates `dist`, you could just plug in that function instead of the dictionary that I have used.

Answer (score 2):

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['location1','location2'],['S1','S2','S3']],
    names=['loc','S'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), 
                  index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns = header)

print(df)

Out[1]:
    loc location1                     location2                    
    S          S1        S2        S3        S1        S2        S3
    a    0.503357 -0.461202 -1.412865  0.866237  1.290292  0.635869
    b   -0.904658 -1.190422 -0.198654 -0.916884 -1.070291 -1.918091
    c   -1.448068 -0.121475 -0.838693  0.047861 -0.131904  1.154370
    d    1.758752 -0.094962 -2.035204 -0.399195 -0.756726  1.609393
    e    0.421521  1.134518 -0.809148 -0.543523 -1.161328  1.261901



In[2]:
distances = {
    ('location1','S1'): 200,
    ('location1','S2'): 760,
    ('location1','S3'): 10,
    ('location2','S1'): 1000,
    ('location2','S2'): 340,
    ('location2','S3'): 70,
}

index = df.columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(key[0], key[1], distances[key],) for key in index.get_values()],
    names=[index.get_level_values(0).name,
           index.get_level_values(1).name,
           'dist']
)
print(df)

Out[2]:
    loc  location1                     location2                    
    S           S1        S2        S3        S1        S2        S3
    dist      200       760       10        1000      340       70  
    a     0.503357 -0.461202 -1.412865  0.866237  1.290292  0.635869
    b    -0.904658 -1.190422 -0.198654 -0.916884 -1.070291 -1.918091
    c    -1.448068 -0.121475 -0.838693  0.047861 -0.131904  1.154370
    d     1.758752 -0.094962 -2.035204 -0.399195 -0.756726  1.609393
    e     0.421521  1.134518 -0.809148 -0.543523 -1.161328  1.261901



In[3]:
result = df.sortlevel(level=2, axis=1)
print(result)

Out[3]:
    loc  location1 location2 location1 location2 location1 location2
    S           S3        S3        S1        S2        S2        S1
    dist      10        70        200       340       760       1000
    a    -1.412865  0.635869  0.503357  1.290292 -0.461202  0.866237
    b    -0.198654 -1.918091 -0.904658 -1.070291 -1.190422 -0.916884
    c    -0.838693  1.154370 -1.448068 -0.131904 -0.121475  0.047861
    d    -2.035204  1.609393  1.758752 -0.756726 -0.094962 -0.399195
    e    -0.809148  1.261901  0.421521 -1.161328  1.134518 -0.543523
```

Comment: Looks good. I have to play around a bit with it, to see if I can adapt it to my real data. Can you please elaborate a bit on the `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(key[0], key[1], distances[key],) for key in index.get_values()],
    names=[index.get_level_values(0).name,
           index.get_level_values(1).name,
           'dist']
)` part? I am not 100% sure what exactly it does.

Comment: The point of that line is to create the `MultiIndex` from scratch, keeping the level values from the original `index` and adding a new level for `dist`.  

I am using the `from_tuples` constructor for the `MultiIndex`.  You have to pass it a list of tuples, where each tuple contains info for an entry in the index.  You also pass it `names`, which will be used to set the level names.  

In this case the desired `MultiIndex` has three levels,  therefore each tuple in the list of tuples has `len==3`, just like the `names` list.

Comment: To create the list of tuples needed in `from_tuples` I used a list comprehension,  iterating over `index.get_values()`.   Here `index.get_values()` gives us a handy representation of the original `MultiIndex` as a list of `tuples`.    Since the original `MultiIndex` has two levels, I can access the values via `key[0]` and `key[1]`.