# How to select a subset of values from a named column level in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's say we have a `DataFrame` with multiple levels of column headers.

```
level_0         A                   B                   C          
level_1         P                   P                   P          
level_2         x         y         x         y         x         y
0       -1.027155  0.667489  0.314387 -0.428607  1.277167 -1.328771
1        0.223407 -1.713410  0.480903 -3.517518 -1.412756  0.718804
```

I want to select a list of columns from a named level.

```
required_columns = ['A', 'B']
required_level = 'level_0'
```

**Method 1: (deprecated in favor of df.loc)**

```
print df.select(lambda x: x[0] in required_columns, axis=1)
```

The problem with this is that I have to specify the level with 0. It fails if I use the name of the level.

**Method 2:**

```
print df.xs('A', level=required_level, axis=1)
```

The problem with this is that I can only specify a single value.  It fails if I use ['A', 'B'].

**Method 3:**

```
print df.ix[:, df.columns.get_level_values(required_level).isin(required_columns)]
```

This works, but isn't as concise as the previous two methods! :)

**Question:**

How can I get method 1 or 2 to work? Or, is there a more pythonic way?

**The MWE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'],
                                     ['P'],
                                     ['x', 'y']],
                                    names=['level_0',
                                           'level_1',
                                           'level_2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(2, 6),
    columns=header
)

required_columns = ['A', 'B']
required_level = 'level_0'

print df
print df.select(lambda x: x[0] in required_columns, axis=1)
print df.xs('A', level=required_level, axis=1)
print df.ix[:, df.columns.get_level_values(required_level).isin(required_columns)]
```

**Related questions**:

1. [pandas dataframe select columns in multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189575/pandas-dataframe-select-columns-in-multiindex)
2. [Giving a column multiple indexes/headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370402/giving-a-column-multiple-indexes-headers)

Comment: While it's surprising there is not a better way, I think your method 3 is the best available at them moment. It's very readable.

Comment: fyi, `ix` was deprecated in pandas 0.20.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix

Comment: `df.select()` is deprecated in favor of `df.loc()` since pandas 0.21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.reindex(columns=required_columns, level=required_level)
```

The resulting output:

```
level_0         A                   B          
level_1         P                   P          
level_2         x         y         x         y
0       -1.265558  0.681565 -0.553084 -1.340652
1        1.705043 -0.512333 -0.785326  0.968391
```

Comment: `reindex` is nice, but of course it would only return a view of the dataframe. Any subsequent modifications wouldn't be reflected in the original.  This might be fine, but really depends on the use case and what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)?  It generally requires the columns to first be sorted (in the original dataframe, they were already sorted).

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[required_columns, :, :]]
# Output:
# level_0         A                   B          
# level_1         P                   P          
# level_2         x         y         x         y
# 0        0.079368 -1.083421  0.129979 -0.558004
# 1       -0.157843 -1.176632 -0.219833  0.935364
```

**Update**

The method you choose really depends why you are selecting your data in the first place and whether or not you need to modify your original data via your selection.

First, to make the example a little more challenging, let's use a MultiIndex dataframe that has the same values across different levels and that is unsorted.

```
required_columns = ['A', 'B']  # Per original question.
required_level = 'level_0'  # Per original question.

np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('BAC'), list('AB')], names=['level_0', 'level_1'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, len(idx)), columns=idx)
>>> df
# Output:
# level_0         B                   A                   C          
# level_1         A         B         A         B         A         B
# 0        1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
# 1        0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
```

***Return a copy of the data***

If you only need to view the data, either directly or for subsequent calculations in a pipeline, then the `reindex` method mentioned by @root and discussed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#data-alignment-and-using-reindex) in the documentation is a good option.

```
df2 = df.reindex(columns=required_columns, level=required_level)
>>> df2
# Output:
# level_0         A                   B          
# level_1         A         B         A         B
# 0        0.978738  2.240893  1.764052  0.400157
# 1       -0.103219  0.410599  0.950088 -0.151357
```

*However*, if you try to modify this dataframe, the changes won't be reflected in your original.

```
df2.iloc[0, 0] = np.nan
>>> df  # Check values in original dataframe.  None are `NaN`.
# Output:
# level_0         B                   A                   C          
# level_1         A         B         A         B         A         B
# 0        1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
# 1        0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
```

***Modify the data***

An alternative method is to use boolean indexing with `loc`. You can use a conditional list comprehension to select the desired columns together with `get_level_values`:

```
cols = [col in required_columns for col in df.columns.get_level_values(required_level)]
>>> df.loc[:, cols]
# Output:
# level_0         B                   A          
# level_1         A         B         A         B
# 0        1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
# 1        0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599
```

If you are slicing the index instead of the columns, then one would obviously need to change `df.columns.get_level_values` to `df.index.get_level_values` in the code snippet above.

You can also modify the original data using `loc`:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[:, cols] = 1
>>> df2
# Output:
# level_0  B     A            C          
# level_1  A  B  A  B         A         B
# 0        1  1  1  1  1.867558 -0.977278
# 1        1  1  1  1  0.144044  1.454274
```

**Conclusion**

Although `select` is a good option for returning a view of your multi-indexed data, boolean indexing using `loc` allows you to view or modify your data.

Instead of **Method 1** or **Method 2**, I would use the `loc` approach described above.

As of pandas 0.20.0, the `ix` method has been deprecated.  I would not recommend **Method 3**.

Comment: Since it is the first one, I think `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[required_columns]]` would also work

Comment: Yes, but using `:, :` reads more clearly that there are two additional levels that are not being sliced (in my opinion).

Comment: It would do the job, but I'd like to be able to identify the level by name as I've said in the question. The reason is that I may not always know how many levels there are, or which one I'm after. All I know is the name of the level.

Comment: If you know the `required_columns`, then why wouldn't @ayhan's comment work?  In fact, even `df.loc[:, slice('A','B')]` is viable (no `IndexSlice` needed).

Comment: @andrew_reece Because you can have the same `required_columns` across different index levels (e.g. column `A` could be in both `level_1' and 'level_2').