# Use multiple rows as column header for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe that I've imported as follows.

```
df = pd.read_excel("./Data.xlsx", sheet_name="Customer Care", header=None)
```

I would like to set the first three rows as column headers but can't figure out how to do this.  I gave the following a try:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0:3,:]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I saw something similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32374280/2540204) answer.  But it only applies if all sub columns are going to be named the same way, which is not necessarily the case.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    "./Data.xlsx", 
    sheet_name="Customer Care", 
    header=[0,1,2]
)
```

This will tell pandas to read the first three rows of the excel file as multiindex column labels.

If you want to modify the rows after you load them then set them as columns

```
#set the first three rows as columns
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[0:3].values)
#delete the first three rows (because they are also the columns
df=df.iloc[3:]
```

Comment: And a great name you have chosen.

Comment: thanks for the response.  Is there any way to set the header after I import the excel sheet?  I should have specified this in the question but I need to modify those rows before they're ready to be headers.

Comment: @neanderslob I've edited the answer to address this.