# How to handle data when there are two header rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I had put a file into **pandas dataframe**, i have 2 header rows here.
which goes by column-1,response  ;     column-2, response etc.

```
Column -1   Column-2    Which of the following Marvel films have you seen?  Please select all that apply.   
Response    Response    Avengers              Iron Man

Yes           No        Avengers              Iron Man
Yes           No        Avengers              Iron Man
Yes           Yes       Avengers              Iron Man
Yes           Yes       Avengers              Iron Man
Yes           No        Avengers              Iron Man
```

This is what i used; to merge both the header rows as 1 column. But, this give me a **multi header index** .

```
    data = pd.read_csv("D:\\Users\\703228597\\Documents\\python\\StarWars.csv" ,header = [0,1],encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

If i want to perform EDA's, what is the **Column_name** i use ?
 since, it is a multi-index header

```
data1[data1.Column_name < 0]
```

Comment: Don't post jpeg pictures but sample code, so that your problem is reproducible. It's also necessary to articulate, how the final solution should look like. In your case read_csv() most likely ends up with a multiindex dataframe?

Comment: i have modified the question

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', header = 1)
```

This looks like it should work. Not too sure what you're trying to achieve. 
I'm guessing you want to index the id column.

```
df = df.set_index('id_column')
```

however, if you're looking for two headers, your question is answered here:
[Giving a column multiple indexes/headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370402/giving-a-column-multiple-indexes-headers)