# Break dataframe header into multiheader

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

| Names | ABCBaseCIP00 | ABCBaseCIP01 | ABCBaseCIP02 | ABC1CIP00 | ABC1CIP01 | ABC1CIP02 | ABC2CIP00 | ABC2CIP01 | ABC2CIP02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Y | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Z | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

I have above dataframe, I am looking to break column headers by name(`ABCBase|ABC1|ABC2)` and code(`CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02|CIP00|CIP01|CIP02`) to get below table as output.

Can anyone suggest how can that be done in pandas? This is dynamic data so do not want to hardcode anything.

|  | ABCBase | ABCBase | ABCBase | ABC1 | ABC1 | ABC1 | ABC2 | ABC2 | ABC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Names | CIP00 | CIP01 | CIP02 | CIP00 | CIP01 | CIP02 | CIP00 | CIP01 | CIP02 |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Y | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Z | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370402/giving-a-column-multiple-indexes-headers) answer your question? Or are you really looking for separate headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using string manipulation and pd.MultiIndex with `from_arrays`:

```
df = df.set_index('Names')

cols = df.columns.str.extract('(ABC(?:Base|\d))(.*)')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([cols[0], cols[1]], names=[None, None])

df
```

Output:

```
      ABCBase              ABC1              ABC2            
        CIP00 CIP01 CIP02 CIP00 CIP01 CIP02 CIP00 CIP01 CIP02
Names                                                        
X           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
Y           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
Z           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

Or,

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex\
               .from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.extract('(ABC(?:Base|\d))(.*)')\
               .to_numpy()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'names' : ['x','y','z'],
         'ABCBaseCIP00' : [1,1,1],
         'ABCBaseCIP01' : [2,2,2],
         'ABCBaseCIP02' : [3,3,3],
         'ABC1CIP00' : [4,4,4],
         'ABC1CIP01' : [5,5,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives

```
    names   ABCBaseCIP00    ABCBaseCIP01    ABCBaseCIP02    ABC1CIP00   ABC1CIP01
0   x       1               2               3               4           5
1   y       1               2               3               4           5
2   z       1               2               3               4           5
```

Now do the work

```
df1 = df.T
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1['name']=df1['index'].str[-5:]
df1['subname']=df1['index'].str[0:-5]

df1 = df1.drop('index',axis=1)
df1 = df1.T
```

which gives

```
            0       1       2       3       4       5
0           x       1       2       3       4       5
1           y       1       2       3       4       5
2           z       1       2       3       4       5
name        names   CIP00   CIP01   CIP02   CIP00   CIP01
subname     ABCBase ABCBase ABCBase ABC1    ABC1    ABC1
```

Which is not quite what you want but is it close enough?

Answer (score 0):

a one-line solution to this problem:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('(CIP.+)', expand=True).droplevel(2)
```

full example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Index
df = DataFrame(
  { 'ABCBaseCIP00': [1,1,1],
    'ABCBaseCIP01': [2,2,2],
    'ABCBaseCIP02': [3,3,3],
    'ABC1CIP00': [4,4,4],
    'ABC1CIP01': [5,5,5] }, 
  index=Index(list('XYZ'), name='Names')
  )
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('(CIP.+)', expand=True).droplevel(2)
# df outputs:
      ABCBase              ABC1      
        CIP00 CIP01 CIP02 CIP00 CIP01
Names                                
X           1     2     3     4     5
Y           1     2     3     4     5
Z           1     2     3     4     5
```

how it works:

1. the regex `CIP.+` matches the from start of level-2. The *brackets* `()` create a capture group so it is returned by `.str.split`
2. splitting and & expanding an index creates a multi-index
3. the resulting multi index has an extra level, which is dropped with `.droplevel(2)`