# Pandas DF column headers not aligned with columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, format

I'm using a Python3 dictionary to hold nested data of the format:

```
{'col1':
    {'row1': '1_1',
     'row2': '1_2'},
 'col2':  
    {'row1': '2_1',
     'row2': '2_2'},
  ...
}
```

The column header's are all 2 characters long, ie. "C1", while the row headers can be up to 30 characters long. The row values can be up to 20 characters long, and are sandwiched by shell colour strings (ie. '\033[95m'), but are on average 3.

When I pass the dictionary into a data frame and print it, I get an output that looks like the snippet below.

```
                        C1                    C2                    C3         ...    
row1_name   1_1     1_2     1_3      1_4      1_5  1_6  1_7     1_8      1_9   ...   
row2_name   2_1     2_2     2_3      2_4      2_5  2_6  2_7     2_8      2_9   ...
row3_n...   3_1     3_2     3_3      3_4      3_5  3_6  3_7     3_8      3_9   ...
```

The column headers are spread over the entire width of the terminal, while the columns are spread over only the necessary width to fit them in based on the max width of the data in each column. This is true even though only the first and last few columns are being displayed with ellipses in the middle (ie. C1 C2 C3 ... C18 C19 C20).

To be clear, the same number of columns and headers are being displayed, but over different widths. Additionally the problem is not that I am not displaying all columns, but that the columns that I am displaying are not aligned with the headers.

I was expecting the columns to be aligned with the headers by default, but I haven't used a dictionary to store data for a DF before. I've tried setting a maximum col width with `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 20)`  and it reduced the spacing of the headers, but not by enough. When I set it to 10, the column values become a single character, while there are still multiple spaces between each header.

#### EDIT1:

When trying to produce mock data I removed the colour strings which resolved the issue. Apparently surrounding data values with shell colour codes adds width to pd column headers but not the values.

#### EDIT2:

Issue resolved: I added escape codes (the same length as the colour codes) to the column headers. This aligned the columns correctly. Seems to be a bug with Pandas.

#### To Reproduce:

- Save csv file to mock_data.csv
- Load data to pd dataframe
- Replace any data value with itself surrounded by colour codes
- Print DF

CSV:

```
,0,1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
XXXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXXXXXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXXXXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
X,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
XXXXXXXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,"XXX, XXX",XXX
XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mock_data.csv')
df['1'].iloc[1] = '\033[91m' + df['1'].iloc[1] + '\033[0m'
print(df)
```

Comment: Check if multiIndex is what you need. Check the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370402/giving-a-column-multiple-indexes-headers)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that is not what I need. My columns only have a single index/header, the header is just not aligned with the relevant column

Comment: My main intuition is that this is an issue with converting a dictionary to a DF but I haven't been able to find anything applicable online.

Comment: Can you provide code to set up a reproducible example?

Comment: The data is private so I'll need some time to produce mock data, let me get back to you

Comment: Removing the colour codes changed the column header spacing to default. Might be a bug with Pandas.

Comment: @Rufus please let me know when you add a reproducible example, I'll reopen the question and you will be able to post your workaround as self-answer.

Comment: @mozway I've added code to reproduce it. My workaround was to add colour codes (the same number of characters as the colours used in the cell values) to the data frame headers. This fixed alignment. I think this is a bug with pandas,

Comment: @Rufus I reopened, please add your workaround, and if you can please [report a bug to pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: @mozway thanks for reopening, I've added my workaround and will report the bug

Comment: Thanks @Rufus and hopefully this gets solved in the future, keep us updated (you can add the bug report link in your answer).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is a display bug with Pandas. The values in each cell were sandwiched between bash colour code escape sequences, for example: `"\033[91msVALUE\033[0m"`. This example has 14 hidden characters in the cell. Pandas then included the escaped characters in the total column width for the column headers (but not when displaying the cells).

###### Workaround:

I added colour/end codes to the column headers. This removed the additional spacing. The colour code must be the same number of characters in the body and header for this to work. In my solution I set the colour to `CYAN='\033[96m'` for my headers, as this had the same number of characters as the body (`RED='\033[91m'` / `GREEN='\033[92m'`). This means that for my example, style options like `BOLD='\033[1m'`, `UNDERLINE='\033[4m'` and `WHITE='\033[0m'` would not align the text correctly if applied to the header.

Headers were updated with the following code:

```
def color_columns(column):
    return bash_colors.CYAN + column + bash_colors.END

display_df.columns = color_columns(df.columns)
```

###### [GitHub - Bug Report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55122)